# Is it possible to create controller filters?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, filter

I have an authentication filter that I want to put on all my actions in a given controller.

Is it possible to add a filter at the controller level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is then applied to all actions automatically.

```
[MyFilter]
public class MyController : Controller {

  // automatically has MyFilter logic attached to it
  public ViewResult MyAction() {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's literally as simple as putting the ActionFilter attribute at the class level instead of the action level.